# Convert HTML to PDF using iText with special char fail

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, xmlworker

I'm facing a problem by using iText and XMLWorkerHelper for a specific case. I generate multiple PDF files with multiple pages without problem but sometimes, an error occur with special characters.

I tested my template and it's not a problem with my HTML, even if the exception say :

```
Exception thrown: 'iTextSharp.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException' in itextsharp.xmlworker.dll

Additional information: Invalid nested tag tr found, expected closing tag td.
```

This error is due to the character : & which is added into my template.

```
<td>Launch C&O</td>
```

I don't exactly know how to resolve this error, is it an encoding error ? Should I specify an encoding mode when I create the PDF ?

This is the code which create a PDF :

```
public async Task Generate(Stream stream, List<string> contentPages)
        {
                try
                {
                    int cpt = 1;
                    Document document = new Document();
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    document.Open();

                    foreach (string pdfContentPage in contentPages)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            document.NewPage();
                            using (StringReader srHtml = new StringReader(pdfContentPage ))
                            {
                                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, srHtml);
                            }
                            ++cpt;
                        }
                        catch (RuntimeWorkerException ex)
                        {
                            Console.Write($"An error occured at PDF generation for cpt = {cpt}");
                            Console.Write(ex.Message);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Content Error : pdfContentPage}");
                            throw;
                        }
                    }

                    document.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
}
```

If you have an advice, I'm glad to read it ! :)

Comment: Replace `&` with `&amp;` and see what happens.

Comment: It didn't change anything, thanks for your purpose :)

Comment: Run your HTML through the W3C validator on https://validator.w3.org/check and check *Clean up Markup with HTML-Tidy*. Compare with your original HTML. Try again with the cleaned HTML at the bottom of the page. You can automate this in your own code with *JTidy*.

Comment: I just discover a solution (or partial solution) by using : new System.Xml.Linq.XText(myString).ToString() for each value that I need to add into my template.

Comment: Very strange error description. I have been looking for this issue for many days. Thankfully find the actual issue and solution in this post. I have resolved it by replacing the **&** character like this: 
`string htmlText = templateHTML.Replace("&", "&amp;");`

Answer (score 2):

At the query binding field where & symbol comes i used a replace function for all describtion's For example at the bind `grid s(2)=" TEST & TEST"`

```
for loop
dim desc as string

desc="TEST & TEST"

desc=desc.replace("&"," ")

s(2)= desc

end of loop
```

Thus the issue was solved in my case

Answer (score 0):

Try with below logic

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(srHtml.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

With, xmlworker 5.5.12 and itextpdf 5.5.12 version

Comment: As has already found out in the comments to the question, the problem was caused by invalid XML; your code would not have helped.